# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, import

```
//imports.ts
import express from "express";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

const _imports = {
  main:{
    express,
    dotenv:dotenv.config(),
  },
  db:{
    MongoConnect:MongoConnect()
};

export default _imports
```

```
//app.ts

import _imports from './imports';

_imports.main.dotenv
_imports.db.MongoConnect
console.log(process.env.SECRET) 
//working well
```

```
//another_file.ts inside 

import _imports from "../../imports";

_imports.main.dotenv
console.log(process.env.SECRET)
//UNDEFINED
```

```
//FOLDER STRUCTURE
app.ts
imports.ts
src
└── api
    └── v1
        └── another_file.ts
```

I have an 'imports.ts' file where I consolidate all my imports. I write them once in this file and then import them from other files to improve readability and reduce complexity. However, when I import them in 'app.ts,' it works without any issues, but in another file, I get an error that says, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')." What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just a practice you should abandon. Yes, there is some argument to be made that a dozen imports is less readable than one, but look at this. You've got a problem I doubt which would occur had you done it the "regular" way. Furthermore, this just makes tree-shaking completely impossible. Not to mention that it's gonna inflate the dependency tree, or the fact that adding or removing imports/exports is going to take longer as you go back and forth from the imports file to other files.

Comment: thanks for advice. Is there an efficient way to manage imports in a more organized manner?

Comment: Your IDE should handle everything for you. It should auto-import things when you type them, and automatically remove unused imports.

Comment: Actually, in this application, the IDE was making the arrangements for me. When I type "_imports.main", the next step can be monitored by the IDE.

What I'm really looking for
[code block]
//imports.js
module.exports = {
   main: {
     express: require("express"),
     db: require(`./mongo`),

},
};

//app.js
const _import = require("./imports");
_import.main.db.connectMongo();

implementing this type of organization for typescript

Comment: I agree, not a good practice, but it should still work (call it `env` instead of imports).
Do you have any _index_ files? It's easy to create circular imports and in some cases you'll end up with undefined stuff until the whole cycle is resolved. Also, try to put your code in functions not in the file's body.

Comment: If this isn't a good try, I don't need to try, I guess I should just stick to the beaten track.